# VBA Simple Code for input and then display using ElseIF

Tags: vba, excel

Here's My Code--- i'v merged **Cells B7:C8** hence want to output values in that range. This is a `TextBox` where I want to input the value and then according to the code display a number in **Range B7:C8**. The error I've been getting in the last line is

> Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

```
Private Sub TextBox21_Change()

Dim Agevar As Integer

If Agevar >= 40 And Agevar <= 45 Then
    Worksheets("Scorecard").Range("B7:c8").Values = 4
ElseIf Agevar >= 60 Then
    Worksheets("Scorecard").Range("b7:c8").Values = 3
ElseIf Agevar >= 30 And Agevar <= 40 Then
    Worksheets("Scorecard").Range("b7:c8").Values = 2
Else
    Worksheets("Scorecard").Range("b7:c8").Values = 1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range` doesn't have a member named `Values`. Did you mean `Value`?

Comment: Hey jsheeran thanx for the pointout. But the problem is when i'm typing in the no in the textbox its not automatically reflecting the no in range b10. How do i make it display it automatically upon input in the textbox?

Comment: jsheeran i took ur code but the answer in any case is just 1. im not getting any other answer. Also how to make it automatically change the answer when i change the input value in the textbox?

Comment: @VinayakBakshi You are talking about a input value in a textbox but where are those in your code? Where do you input the value `Agevar` ? because if you do not set it somewhere your `If` Statement will always get to `Else` and you will have 1 in your cells.

Comment: So how to go about it then? Its just my third day studying and working VBA. il sure appreciate the help...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `Agevar` should represent the value you enter in the text box?

- Add this before your IF statement:
  `Agevar = Me.TextBox21.Value`  - this will place the value from the textbox into the variable (there's no checking to make sure you put the correct value in the box - it will throw an error with if you enter a letter, or delete all values from the box).
- Remove the `s` from values - it's `Value` as @jsheeran commented.
- Only reference the first cell in your merged cells - `Range(B7)`.